# Is there any way to select/deselect the child tree components of checkbox in swt depending upon the parent selection/deselection respectively?

Tags: swt

When I select top treeitem check box then all subtreeitems checkboxes gets selected and if I deselct the top treeitem then all subtreeitems checkboxes gets deselected. But after deselecting all subtreeitems, I want to select any the subtreeitem checkbox manually How can I implement??

[image]

```java
parentTree= new Tree(mainComp, SWT.CHECK | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);`

TreeItem[] treeItems = dataValidationTree.getItems();
   
for (TreeItem item : treeItems) 
    {    
        TreeItem[] subTreeItems = item.getItems();
        for (TreeItem subItem : subTreeItems)
            {
                boolean checked = item.getChecked(); 
                checkSubTree(item, checked);                    
            }           
    }

private void checkSubTree(TreeItem item,boolean checked) {      
item.setChecked(checked);       
for(TreeItem subItems : item.getItems()) 
    {
        checkSubTree(subItems,checked);
                    
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what the issue is, you can always "manually" click on any of the check boxes.

Comment: Hi gre-449. It does not allow to select it if we click on any of the checkboxex. Also If I select the parent check box then the child components of tree gets selected but I cant manually deselect any of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use a selection listener to check all of the subtree you would do it like this:

```java
Tree checkTree = new Tree(shell, SWT.CHECK ...

...

checkTree.addListener(SWT.Selection, event ->
    {
      TreeItem item = (TreeItem)event.item;

      for (TreeItem subItems : item.getItems())
        checkSubTree(subItems, item.getChecked());
    });

...

private static void checkSubTree(TreeItem item, boolean checked)
{
  item.setChecked(checked);

  for (TreeItem subItems : item.getItems())
    checkSubTree(subItems, checked);
}
```

This only looks at the sub-tree which was selected and will allow individual items to be check/unchecked normally.